# Playing Destiny with a friend in another continent, viable?

Tags: destiny

I moved abroad and I wanted stay in touch with a friend, so we decided to buy a PS4 (we didn't buy it yet) and try to play some games.

This game called Destiny seems fun, but I got a question, are we going to be able to play even when I live in Denmark and he lives in Argentina?. Or the lag is going to be so bad that it's not gonna work?.

The idea is to play coop missions, don't really care about PvP or anything like that.

Answer (score 1):

Since nothing is getting updated in here.

Playing Co-op across country is completely viable, i have not noticed any connection problems so while playing internationally, including my very bad internet and a Type-3 NAT on my PS4 (which heavily influences online play usually)

The Distance i played was from Germany with Canada and Hungary and we had no problems with lag whatsoever.

Quick edit: After reading up on it a bit more, turns out Destiny uses a Hybrid networking system of Server-Client based play and Peer-to-Peer connections. It switches to a non non-critical Peer-2-Peer Connections during open roaming areas and then switches to dedicated Servers for the critical Strikes and Raids. Which is the complete opposite of what i expected

Comment: Oh, that's interesting, didn't know that, and since we only really care about campaign co-op, that wont be a problem. Good to know thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I googled a bit and saw multiple people saying it is possible to play cross region. The latency should not be a problem, from my own experience with cross region servers your latency will be around the 150-200 ms range.

If anyone has had experience with destiny across region please leave a comment and i will update this post.

Comment: I've read that Destiny uses a P2P host-client model, wich means the host (me or my friend) will have no lag at all, while the other will. Is this the case?, I'm having a hard time trying to find conclusive information.

Comment: You are correct. The player hosting will not experience any lag, and the person who isn't hosting will experience the lag.

Comment: I've been playing Destiny with friends in different continents without any problems, in PVE we have never noticed any lag, in PVP however is where the lag will come out. Can't tell if it's like this for anyone else though. And i don't have the greatest internet, so it should work just fine